# Identifying episodes with R

Tags: r, subset, data-analysis

I'm working with an unbalanced panel that contains information across various countries for several years.
One of the variables I have is dist, which represents the log-deviations from HP-filtered GDP. If dist>1, then dummy=1.

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Benin", 
"Burundi", "Cameroon", "Chile", "Cyprus", "Ecuador", "Equatorial Guinea", 
"Gabon", "Ghana", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "India", 
"Jamaica", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Mali", 
"Mexico", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nepal", "Nicaragua", "Niger", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Peru", "Rwanda", 
"Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = c("pseries", "factor"
)), date = structure(c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1965", "1966", "1967", 
"1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", 
"1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", 
"1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), dist = c(-2.44153863355447, 
-0.565497304455015, 1.4222058591902, 1.18583114700364, 0.936095936859405, 
-0.40582369098349, 2.08296049774769, -1.59377116576285, 0.316969269882462, 
-0.562808458278515, -0.438155688763343, 0.824980940313303, -0.60293744113302, 
0.397182279339227, 1.34777053122572, 0.00539983501313633, 0.0528824118570846, 
-0.838507946421168, 0.220969370384196, -1.06945294612116, 0.157324834050942, 
0.244080457191975, 0.215931770884978, 0.226176571912671, 0.197663973781873, 
0.183399695771442, 0.334605869075331, 0.0683789169881243, -0.0432432418415798, 
-0.191834311017179, -0.368292801016647, -0.572222256415503, -0.838601784768107, 
-1.15213567684887, -1.49844386483361, 2.39265920977342, 1.90573467650352, 
1.3362714819111, 0.158391029649629, 1.12699318386612, 2.38996532864524
), dummy = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 400L, 
401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 
412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to identify episodes in the following way based on the values of dist  and dummy.
An episode is defined as the time spam for which values of dist>0.5, conditioned on dist>= 1 at some point.
In the example above, the episode from Bangladesh lasts for 3 years from 1978-1980 and the one for Guatemala lasts for another 3 years from 2006 to 2008
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please make your example reproducible? Without `frame` we can't run any of the code you've shared.

Comment: I'm sorry Gregor, I'm new to R and Stack Overflow. How do I make the example reproducible?

Comment: Sharing the data via `dput()` is the nicest way. `dput(DT[1:10, ])` would give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of `DT`. Choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I think I just did.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just as an FYI, `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is an anti-pattern you should avoid, `data.frame(...)` is strictly better. In this case all your data is numeric so it doesn't matter, but `cbind` creates a matrix, so if you had mixed data types they would all be coerced to `character`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would include the expected result for the sample data. (I think you had this before?) I'm pretty sure I understand your definition of episodes, but I don't know how you want them marked in the result. I'm also making some  assumptions I'd like to check: (1) All episodes are contained within an ID? (2) An episode ends when `x <= 0.5`? (3) `y` has nothing to do with the definition of episodes?

Comment: Is this better? I pasted some of my data
I want to be able to get a vector identifying all episodes (1 for episodes, 0 for no episodes), and calculate the duration of all episodes. 
1) yes, all episodes are contained in a ID
2) yes, an episodes ends when dist<0.5
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want. I use `dplyr` for the data manipulation, but also the utility function `rleid` from the `data.table` package.

```
x %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(
    potential_episode_grp = (dist > 0.5) * data.table::rleid(dist > 0.5)
  ) %>%
  group_by(country, potential_episode_grp) %>%
  mutate(episode = as.integer(potential_episode_grp > 0 & any(dist > 1)))
# # A tibble: 11 × 6
# # Groups:   country, potential_episode_grp [4]
#    country     date   dist dummy episode potential_episode_grp
#    <chr>      <int>  <dbl> <int>   <int>                 <int>
#  1 Bangladesh  1976 -2.44      0       0                     0
#  2 Bangladesh  1977 -0.565     0       0                     0
#  3 Bangladesh  1978  1.42      1       1                     2
#  4 Bangladesh  1979  1.19      1       1                     2
#  5 Bangladesh  1980  0.936     0       1                     2
#  6 Guatemala   2004 -0.390     0       0                     0
#  7 Guatemala   2005 -0.267     0       0                     0
#  8 Guatemala   2006  1.46      1       1                     2
#  9 Guatemala   2007  0.763     0       1                     2
# 10 Guatemala   2008  1.11      1       1                     2
# 11 Guatemala   2009  0.289     0       0                     0
```

---

Using this data:

```
x = read.table(text = ' country       date  dist       dummy episode
1  Bangladesh 1976 -2.4415386     0   0
2  Bangladesh 1977 -0.5654973     0   0
3  Bangladesh 1978  1.4222059     1   1
4  Bangladesh 1979  1.1858311     1   1
5  Bangladesh 1980  0.9360959     0   1
560  Guatemala 2004 -0.3899023    0   0
561  Guatemala 2005 -0.2672316    0   0
562  Guatemala 2006  1.4632532    1   1
563  Guatemala 2007  0.7633748    0   1
564  Guatemala 2008  1.1143216    1   1
565  Guatemala 2009  0.2891909    0   0', header =T)
```

Comment: Gregor, I just used the code you posted, and it seems to work, but it idenfies episodes when dist never reaches 1.
The idea is that an episodes is marked by two things: 1) dist>1; 2) the episodes starts when dist >0.5 and ends when dist<0.5; conditioned on dist reaching 1 within the episode
I attached a larger data sample, if its of any use

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look, but the new data is hard to import due to spaces in some of the country names. Would you please share the sample data with `dput()` so that it is copy/pasteable? Use e.g., `dput(your_data[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows (specify whatever subset makes sense).

Comment: But also I can't reproduce your problem. I just edited the sample data in my answer so that the Guatemala potential episode stays below 1. It is flagged as a potential episode, but the resulting `episode` column does not mark it as an episode because  of my `any(dist > 1)` line. Perhaps I should explain more: the result I compute is the `episode` column, the `potential_episode_grp` is an intermediate column I create and use. I leave it in for transparency, but you can drop after the calculation is complete.

Comment: I think I just did. Is that alright?

Comment: Yup, the `dput()` went well. I ran my code on it, the results look fine to me. Can you be specific about issues you see?

Comment: With the new data, there is concrete example, Bangladesh 1987, where dist<1, but the code you gave me signals it as an episode

Comment: Bangladesh 1987 has `episode = 0` after running my code, as it should be. Please see the earlier comment about the difference between `potential_episode_grp` and `episode`. The output you want is in the `episode` column.